# Geoserver WMS and donut polygons

Tags: geoserver, wms, getmap

I found something strange in how GeoServer serves WMS, specifically how it draws donut polygons.  When the whole polygon is inside WMS GetMap request BBOX, the inner hole of donut polygon is filled. When part of the polygon falls outside WMS request BBOX, the inner hole is not filled.

Is it a bug, a feature or am I doing something wrong?

Tested on GeoServer versions 2.3.3, 2.8.3, 2.9.1.
[image: Example 1. Note the brown polygon]
[image: Example 2. After i zoom in a bit]

Comment: please add some screenshots, details of the style and some example data to allow reproduction

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to upgrade to GeoServer 2.9.2. The multipolygons with holes seem to work now.[image: Example 3]